# Word insertFile at cursor position

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to insert a word file at the current cursor position, but my code always insert a new page. What's wrong with my code?

```
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = word.Documents.Add();
Word.Selection selection = word.Selection;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    selection.InsertFile(@"C:\Users\stevet\Desktop\test.docx");
    selection.TypeParagraph();
    selection = word.Selection;
}
word.Visible = true;
```

Comment: What do you mean with "my code always inserts a new page"? What is your expected output? And what is the content of "test.docx"?

Comment: The content of the test.docx is a header and a small paragraph. I want to insert the content at the cursor position. With the code above I have ten pages with the content in one Word Document.

Comment: Does the document being inserted contain any section breaks? Or is any of the used paragraphs formatted using the *Page break before* option?

Comment: That's it! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word renders page breaks under the following conditions:

- The document contains a manual page break.
- The document contains a section break of type *Next Page*, *Even Page* or *Odd Page*.
- The document contains a section break of type *Continuous* and the page orientation of the two section differs (in fact, Word converts the section break into a *Next Page* section break).
- A paragraph is formatted using the *Page break before* option.

Make sure that none of this is the case in the document being inserted.